# How to check if a specific value is content of a list

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I load a Json from a server, and when there is the value "sign_change_global" in it, the HTML shall show different content. So I think, this is only a HTML problem, or is there something to add in the controller too?

*Json:*

```
[
  "pb_edit",
  "pb_import_execute",
  "role_edit",
  "sign_change_global",
  "sign_change_own",
  "sign_deactivate"
]
```

*JS:*

```
    var getAccountPermission = function () {
      if (AuthService.isAuth()) {
        // check only when authenticated (or refresh possible)
        AccountPermissions.one().get().then(
            function (resultOk) {
              $log.d("AccountPermissions ok: ", resultOk);
              $scope.permissions= resultOk.data;
            },
            function (resultError) {
              $log.d("Accountinfo error: ", resultError);
              ErrorService.showApiError(resultError);
            },
            function (resultNotify) {
              $log.d("Accountinfo notify:", resultNotify);
            }
        );
      }
    };

    getAccountPermission();
```

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-show="permissions.sign_change_global">
  <i> Show this, when "sign_change_global" is in LIST</i><br/>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="40" ng-model="newCustomerSig" ng-trim="false" placeholder="{{user.customer.signature}}"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are checking if a list contains an element then you should use a function to check whether the element exist in that list.so you can use `array.indexOf(element) != -1`

```
$scope.permissionExists(permission){
     if(elementName == undefined){
          return false;
     }else{
          return $scope.permissions.indexOf(permission) != -1;
     }
}
```

and in the markup

```
<div ng-show="permissionExists('sign_change_global')">
  <i> Show this, when "sign_change_global" is in LIST</i><br/>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="40" ng-model="newCustomerSig" ng-trim="false" placeholder="{{user.customer.signature}}"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: i slightly editted the js code, but this works fine! thank you